# How to process includes in a .sol file?

Tags: solidity

How to process all includes in a `.sol` file? I want to produce a file with all includes recursively replaced with the included files content.

Comment: `truffle-flattener` already does that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: @soliditydeveloper.com I (mistakenly) thought that this is the only way to verify a contract of several files at Etherscan. It seems the way, however, if a contract includes contracts from other directories.

Comment: @porton If you are using Truffle, you can check out https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify. It doesn't always work, especially for very new solc versions or proxy contracts for example. But otherwise works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to get verified on Etherscan and generate my ABI is make a directory and place all your .sol files in it, go in to node_modules/@... and get each .sol dependency and place it in the directory you made. Go in to each .sol file in your directory and replace all the include paths to the current directory. Then you can do the multi-file upload to Etherscan, upload each .sol file and Etherscan flattens it all out and compiles it, gives you the ABI and your source is verified.

You do this Automatically with:

```
npm install truffle-flattener —save
```

Then flatten the files this way:

```
./node_modules/.bin/truffle-flattener ./node_modules/@openz
```